# Filtrar diccionario en función de claves

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Quiero importar artículos de la mayor cantidad de fuentes del mundo entero a partir de una fecha determinada.

```
import requests
url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'
       'country=us&'
       'apiKey=de9e19b7547e44c4983ad761c104278f')
response = requests.get(url)

response_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(response.json())

articles = {article for article in response_dataframe['articles'] if article['publishedAt'] == '2019-01-04T11:30:00Z'}
print(articles)
```

Pero obtengo :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-0f21f2f50907> in <module>
      2 response_dataframe['articles'][1]['publishedAt']
      3 
----> 4 articles = {article for article in response_dataframe['articles'] if article['publishedAt'] >= '2018-01-04T11:30:00Z'}
      5 print(articles)

<ipython-input-84-0f21f2f50907> in <setcomp>(.0)
      2 response_dataframe['articles'][1]['publishedAt']
      3 
----> 4 articles = {article for article in response_dataframe['articles'] if article['publishedAt'] >= '2018-01-04T11:30:00Z'}
      5 print(articles)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 1):

### La causa del error

La expresión:

```
articles = { article for article in ... }
```

genera un conjunto (`set()`) debido a las llaves entre las cuales está encerrado. Los elementos de un conjunto no pueden ser cualquier dato, sino solo los que sean *hasheables* (que son aquellos de los que sea posible calcular un *hash* y siempre salga el mismo, lo que implica también que el objeto sea inmutable).

En tu caso, cada `article` es un diccionario. Ya que los diccionarios pueden cambiar de valor, no son *hasheables* y por tanto no pueden ser elementos de un conjunto.

### Posibles soluciones

1. No uses un conjunto, sino una lista. Supongo que la API que utilizas no te está retornando artículos duplicados, por lo que no veo sentido a usar un conjunto para recopilarlos. Por tanto te basta cambiar esa línea para que sea:

   ```
   articles = [ article for article in ... ]
   ```
2. Procesa cada `article` para que en lugar de ser un diccionario sea otro tipo inmutable y *hasheable*, como por ejemplo una cadena (puedes convertir cada diccionario a JSON, por ejemplo) o una `namedtuple`...

### Un enfoque mejor

Si en lugar de crear un dataframe con el resultado de la consulta, utilizas sólo el campo `["articles"]` de ese resultado, el dataframe tendrá como columnas los diferentes atributos del artículo, lo que hace más sencillo usar Pandas para su filtrado. Es decir:

```
import requests
import  pandas as pd

url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'
       'country=us&'
       'apiKey=de9e19b7547e44c4983ad761c104278f')
response = requests.get(url)

df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()["articles"])
df.publishedAt = pd.to_datetime(df.publishedAt)
```

Este `df` tiene el siguiente aspecto:

[image: Dataframe]

De este modo resulta más sencillo quedarse, por ejemplo, con los artículos publicados a las 16h:

```
df[df.publishedAt.dt.hour==16]
```

o cualquier otra cosa que se te ocurra y que la potencia de pandas te permita.

Comment: ¿por qué el voto negativo? ¿Hay algún error de forma o fondo en la respuesta?